# How can I fix my physically damaged Samsung Galaxy s5 that won't display the screen?

Tags: screen

My Samsung Galaxy s5 stopped showing anything on th screen after I dropped it.  it still vibrates and makes noises but won't show anything on the screen.  how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond an average android "enthusiast". I would highly recommend contacting your sales agent if you are still under warranty, and if not get the screen replaced from a reputed dealer. It will set you back some money though, but it's still worth than trying to fix it yourself.
Perhaps if you're extremely lucky there might only be some disconnected ribbon, and the screen may still be working, but check it with an expert.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with my S5 which required it to be taken to a Samsung Service Centre - the screen ribbon cable had become detached. (I live in Australia and there happened to be one that was pretty local).

Before taking it to the service centre I recommend trying some of the ideas posted in the following guides:

http://www.technobezz.com/fix-samsung-galaxy-s5-screen-wont-turn-problem/
http://samsungrumors.net/galaxy-s5-black-screen/

The final option is to try and fix the issue yourself. This will void your warranty and I only recommend this as a last resort.

www.ifixit.com/Search?query=samsung%20s5&c-doctype_namespace=guide

Comment: Those links may prove to be helpful so consider adding the relevant parts here so that if the former expires in future, your post would remain helpful as it is now.